# Saving existing document to Folder with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a project that performs a mail merge of form information with a template and emails the documents. Now I need to change so that the documents are saved to a Drive Folder called 'OUTPUT'. Based on my working original code I have:

```
  for (i in templateNamesArray) {

    var templateName = templateNamesArray[i];
    var newNameArray = templateName.split(' of ')        
    var templateid = getTemplateIdByName(templateName);

    var docid = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy(newNameArray[1]).getId();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
    var body = doc.getBody();
    Logger.log(body);
    Object.keys(formObject).forEach(function(key) {
      var field = '%' + key + '%';
      var val = formObject[key];
      body.replaceText(field, val);
    });
    doc.saveAndClose();
    documentArray.push(doc);

  }
```

the merged 'doc' files are saved to an array. Next I tried to loop through the document array with:

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("OUTPUT");

 while (folders.hasNext()) {


var folder = folders.next();

for (i in documentArray) {

  docFile = documentArray[i];
            Logger.log('while3');


  folder.addFile(docFile)


}

}
```

However the line "folder.addFile(docFile)" fails and no files are created in OUTPUT. However they are being saved in the Template folder I presume because of the SaveandClose function. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the file to the `documentArray`, for use within `DriveApp`, using the `DriveApp` method of grabbing the file instead of using the document  from `DocumentApp` should work

```
...

  doc.saveAndClose();
  documentArray.push(DriveApp.getFileById(docid));

}
```

**edit: addFile**

```
for (i in documentArray) {

  folder.addFile(documentArray[i])

}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would you add the documents in documentArray to athe OUTPUT folder?

Comment: The rest of your code should work as is; I used `folder.addFile(documentArray[i])` when testing

Comment: Thanks its very hard to debug when using a form.

Comment: One more question, The doc is still being saved in the template folder, How best to remove it or stop it being saved there?

Comment: You can set the destination with [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder)). The code would need to be re-arranged a bit `DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy(newNameArray[1], folders.next()).getId();`

Comment: Thank you again, actually after looking at your last comment I realized that by selecting where you want to place your document using makecopy (as you explained), you can avoid the need to move it at all.